# Possible water damage from puddles?

Tags: vw, damage, water

Recently drove through what I thought were two shallow puddles this morning. I saw another vehicle like mine actually get stuck after I went through. Now granted his suspension was modified as the car was significantly lower than mine ( VW Gti). Should I be worried about possible damage from going through these massive puddles? I sped through the first one and was going a decent speed on the second one enough to cause a mini bow wave. I was able to get to work turn off and turn on my car afterwards didn’t hear anything wrong yet. Could be worrying way to much about this, but I’ve heard the Gti isn’t good at things like this and unfortunately I don’t have a warranty on the vehicle anymore.

Comment: If the car drove fine afterward, then there shouldn't be anything to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

If the engine ingests water it can fill the bores with water which, being no-compressible, destroys the engine immediately.  This would happen within seconds of entering the puddle and typically only happens when the water level is above the level of the engines air intake.

The only thing you might want to check, and I've had this before on a Golf GTI, is that the air-box and air-filter are dry.  They can get damp and this can cause odd mis-fires and engine hunting as it confuses the air mass sensor.  It's just a case of popping the top off the air-box and checking that the filter is dry to the touch.

Other than that, if the car continues to run and behave as normal, you shouldn't see any further problems.